# Symbol for Phone Number in Resume

Tags: symbols

I've chosen to create my resume in LaTeX  ( out of curiosity ).

I thought printing a "clean" symbol of a phone before my phone_no will look nice ...

Is there such a symbol? any packages?

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol, including non-math symbols like a phone.

Comment: It's also unnecessary unless you want to distinguish a land line from a wireless. Otherwise it's just a phone number, and everyone will recognize this.

Comment: @Emre: unless you're trying to tell aliens how to call you.  They will need to know they first have to locate a device that looks like that before dialing. :-P

Comment: The moderncv package is definitely worth a look. It uses the telephone icon, a cell-phone icon and a few others for the contact-info block. And besides, it just looks good. [moderncv info on ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) gives the following packages and symbols for a (old-fashioned) land-line phone and a mobile phone:

```
\usepackage{wasysym}
\phone
```

[image]

```
\usepackage{marvosym}
\Mobilefone
```

[image]

Comment: I really like the \Mobilefone symbol . Thank you :)

Answer (score 40):

You can easily find such symbols in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). For example, from bbding, wasysym and ifsym:

[image]

Just look out for `\Phone`, `\phone` and `\Telephone`.

Answer (score 29):

The `marvosym` package provides `\Telefon`:

[image]

Comment: looks decent . I'm going to use this ...

Answer (score 28):

Some more possibilities:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\mobilePhone}{{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"1F4F1}}}
\newcommand*{\clamshellMobilePhone}{{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"1F581}}}
\newcommand*{\phoneA}{{\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"260E}}}
\newcommand*{\phoneB}{{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"260E}}}
\newcommand*{\phoneC}{{\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"260E}}}
\newcommand*{\phoneWhiteA}{{\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"260F}}}
\newcommand*{\phoneWhiteB}{{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"260F}}}
\newcommand*{\phoneWhiteC}{{\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"260F}}}
\newcommand*{\phoneReceiverA}{{\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"1F4DE}}}
\newcommand*{\phoneReceiverB}{{\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"1F4DE}}}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newcommand*\faMobile{{\FA\symbol{"F10B}}}

\begin{document}
    Mobile phones: 
    \mobilePhone\clamshellMobilePhone\faMobile

    Normal phones:
    \phoneA\phoneB\phoneC\phoneWhiteA\phoneWhiteB\phoneWhiteC

    Telephone receivers:
    \phoneReceiverA\phoneReceiverB\faPhone
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to use the third mobile phone symbol in `pdfLaTeX`?

Comment: @MarioS.E. Sorry, no.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi what is the command of Skype Icon. Any idea about skype icon

Comment: @MickyK http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=faSkype

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I want to put the Skype Icon in Europass CV

Comment: @MickyK I do not know such thing. Please ask a new question if you can't find a solution by searching "Skype" here.

Comment: @MarioS.E. Yes there is a very similar symbol `\faMobilePhone` in the package `fontawesome`

Answer (score 1):

I found the [`fontawesome5`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5) package very helpful and easy to use. First found in this link: https://latexdraw.com/fontawesome-ready-icons-to-use-in-latex/

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
    Telephone: 
    \faIcon{phone} \faIcon{phone-alt} \faIcon{phone-slash} \faIcon{phone-square} \faIcon{phone-square-alt} 
    
    Mobile: 
    \faIcon{mobile} \faIcon{mobile-alt}
\end{document}
```

[image: phone-images]