# calendar symbol

Tags: symbols

Similar to [Symbol for Phone Number in Resume](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16586/symbol-for-phone-number-in-resume), is there a LaTeX command for a calendar symbol?

[image]

Comment: You can also use TikZ or PSTricks to draw a symbol.

Comment: You can simply have the picture available in some graphic format, probably PDF, and use `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package `fontawesome` provides some symbols. You can also use TikZ or PSTricks. A **very simple** appraoch using TikZ is shown in the MWE too.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\faCalendar\qquad\faCalendarEmpty

\newcommand\myday{\fill[gray!80] (0,0)(.25,.25);}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\fill[gray!80,rounded corners=10pt,] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\fill[gray!20,rounded corners=10pt,] (0,1.6) -- (0.01,0.05) -- (1.8,0.2) -- (1.95,1.6) ;
\fill[red!75,rounded corners=10pt] (0,1.5) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,1.5) ;
\foreach \y in { 0.3 , 0.7 , 1.1  } {
 \foreach \x in { 0.2 , 0.6 , 1.0 , 1.4 } {
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\x cm,yshift=\y cm]
   \fill[gray!80] (0,0) rectangle (.25,.25);
  \end{scope}
 }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: ! fontspec error: "font-not-found" ! Would the TikZ solution be tough?

Comment: @Marco: Do you use an updated TeX Live or MikTeX version?

Comment: I think I do... However, I cannot change my "type setting engine" to "lualatex". Instead, I have used "xelatex"...

Comment: @Marco: I edited my answer. I am sure any TikZ expert can improve my TikZ "waste".

Comment: I have finally managed to use \faCalendar. Thank you for providing more than one solution! (+1)